# Can I lend my games to friends?

Tags: xbox-one

A friend is thinking about getting the Xbox One and I would like to lend him some games to start with. Can I lend the games to him and continue playing when I get them back?

Since the original statement of Microsoft that games would not be treatable was retracted, I'm still quite unsure if it is possible without problems.

Can I lend my physical games to a friend without consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I lend my physical games to a friend without consequences?

Yes, a physical copy can be shared without consequences.  You will need the disk to play the game (despite being installed to your hard drive), so you cannot have more than one person playing from a physical copy at any one time (minus local co-op, obviously).

You can sell off your physical copy and allow a new owner to play the game.

Just a side note - Online codes associated with a physical game (as well as any downloaded DLC) will be tied to the gamertag / actual console.

Overall, it is the same outcome as sharing games on the Xbox 360.